# The input from main class can't be accessed in the another class and would only display the initialized value

Tags: java

I need to access the inputs from the main class and let them be applied to the department class, however, it won't let me. Also, I am not allowed to use parameters. I need to follow this UML diagram. Please guide me on how can I fix this. Our topic is all about inheritance, static variables and method, method overriding and super keyword.

[image]

```
public class Department {
    private int groupScore;
    private double groupAverage;
    private static int overallScore;
    private static double overallAverage;
    
    public Department(){
        int a = 0; 
        int b = 0; 
        int c = 0; 
        int d = 0; 
        int e = 0;
        
        int gscore = groupScore;
        gscore = a + b + c + d + e;
        
        int oascore = overallScore;
        oascore = overallScore + groupScore;
        
        overallAverage = overallAverage/10.0;
        
        groupAverage = groupScore/5.0;
    }
    public double getGroupAverage() {
        return groupAverage;
    }
    public static void displayAverage() {
        double oave = overallAverage;
        System.out.println("Overall Average: " + oave);
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Department objdept = new Department();
        
        System.out.println("Enter 5 rates for Department A (1-5)");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        int d = sc.nextInt();
        int e = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Department 1 group average: " + objdept.getGroupAverage());
        objdept.getGroupAverage();
        objdept.displayAverage();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter 5 rates for Department B (1-5)");
        int f = sc.nextInt();
        int g = sc.nextInt();
        int h = sc.nextInt();
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        int j = sc.nextInt();
        objdept.getGroupAverage();
        System.out.println("Department 2 group average: "+ objdept.getGroupAverage());
        System.out.println();
        Department.displayAverage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you aren't allowed arguments in the constructor based on the diagram. You could add the scanner code into the Department constructor. Then in the main create two different department objects.

```
public Department(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    int b = sc.nextInt();
    // c,d,e etc...
    groupScore = a + b + c + d + e;
    groupAverage = groupScore / 5.0;

    overallScore = overallScore + groupScore;

    if (overallAverage == 0.0) {
        overallAverage = groupAverage;
    } else {
        overallAverage = (groupAverage + overallAverage) / 2.0;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter 5 rates for Department 1 (1-5)");
        Department department1 = new Department();
        System.out.println("Department 1 group average: " + department1.getGroupAverage());
        Department.displayAverage();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Enter 5 rates for Department 2 (1-5)");
        Department department2 = new Department();
        System.out.println("Department 2 group average: " + department2.getGroupAverage());
        Department.displayAverage();
    }
}
```

**If you are allowed arguments**,
You need to pass in your variables into your Department constructor while creating the object. First create a constructor that takes in 5 integer values

```
public Department(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e){
    groupScore = a + b + c + d + e;
    groupAverage = (a + b + c + d + e) / 5;
}
```

Second pass the values to the constructor in the main method. Like this

```
int a = sc.nextInt();
int b = sc.nextInt();
int c = sc.nextInt();
int d = sc.nextInt();
int e = sc.nextInt();
Department objdept = new Department(a,b,c,d,e);
```

Comment: But based on the uml diagram, we must not use parameters. or is my understanding wrong?

Comment: That does look like the case. I missed that. I added an edit above to move the scanner into the Department class. I hope that isn't against the directions somewhere.

Comment: what would i put in the main class now?

Comment: I updated my answer again to show what is in main. You would need the two `new Department()` calls there.